# Creation of nodes and relationships from a csv of data taken from a relational database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Cypher, and I am trying to create nodes and relationships from data taken from a SQL DB. I have already exported the data as a csv.

Here's a dummy data representation of what my data looks like (The dataset that I'm working on has ~84k rows):

```
membership_id member_id  hotel hotel_location   visit_dt
            1       A11 Hotel1          Texas 2019-01-01
            1       A12 Hotel2          Texas 2019-02-04
            1       A13 Hotel1          Texas 2019-01-01
            2       B11 Hotel3     California 2019-01-25
            2       B12 Hotel2     California 2019-02-04
            2       B13 Hotel3     California 2019-01-25
            2       B12 Hotel1     California 2019-01-01
```

The csv string for the above mentioned data is given below:

```
"membership_id,member_id,hotel,hotel_location,visit_dt\n1,A11,Hotel1,Texas,2019-01-01\n1,A12,Hotel2,NewYork,2019-02-04\n1,A13,Hotel1,Texas,2019-01-01\n2,B11,Hotel3,California,2019-01-25\n2,B12,Hotel2,NewYork,2019-02-04\n2,B13,Hotel3,California,2019-01-25\n2,B12,Hotel1,Texas,2019-01-01"
```

Assume the above mentioned data has been loaded as `dataset`.

The entities that I want to create are:

1. `:Membership{membership_id:dataset.membership_id}`
2. `:Member{member_id:dataset.member_id}`
3. `:Hotel{hotel_name:dataset.hotel}`
4. `:State{state_name:dataset.hotel_location}`

The relationships that I want to create between the above mentioned entites are:

1. `(:Membership)-[:ASSOCIATE]-(:Member)`
2. `(:Member)-[:VISIT{visit_date:dataset.visit_dt}]->(:Hotel)`
3. `(:Hotel)-[:LOCATED_AT{location:dataset.hotel_location}]->(:State)`

Given below is an image of how I want my graph to look like:
[image: example_graph]

To achieve this, I tried the following query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS dataset 
MERGE (ms:Membership{family_id:dataset.patient_family_id}) 
WITH dataset, ms 
MERGE (m::Member{member_id:dataset.member_id})
WITH dataset, ms, m
MERGE (h:Hotel{hotel_name:dataset.hotel})
WITH ms, m, h, dataset
MERGE (s:State{state_name:dataset.hotel_location})
WITH ms, m, h, s, dataset
MERGE (ms)-[:ASSOCIATE]-(m)
WITH ms, m, h, s, dataset
MERGE (m)-[:VISIT{visit_date:dataset.visit_dt}]->(h)
WITH ms, m, h, s, dataset
MERGE (h)-[:LOCATED_AT{location:dataset.hotel_location}]->(s)
RETURN ms, m, h, s
```

But on running the above mentioned query on the dataset (~84k rows), It remains in execution for a really long time, and I have never been able to reach the state where I can see some results.

So I would like to know a better way (from start to finish) of achieving my result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you have indexes and/or unique constraints on the label/property combinations that you will use to lookup and identify your nodes, that will speed up your matching and merging of nodes.

You'll want to use [USING PERIODIC COMMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) when loading if the CSV is large, that takes care of batching for you.

You may also want to separate node creation from relationship creation, so try using a query just for creating/merging nodes, make a pass through your CSV with that, then use a separate load query to match to your now-created nodes and create the relationships between them.

And don't return the data at the end, there's no need for that and the browser isn't good with handling the return of a ton of rows of data, if that's what you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mr. InverseFalcon. It helped speed up things quite a bit. I was unaware of the concept of indexes in neo4j before reading your answer, which was probably the reason why my query was inefficient.